# for...loop & if..else statements... how does my code look?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, for-loop

Write the numbers from 1 to 90

Use a for loop

When the number is divisible by 3 write "Fizz"

When the number is divisible by 5 write "Buzz"

When the number is divisible by both 3 and 5, write "FizzBuzz"

After you write "FizzBuzz", display a line break

here is my code:

```
script type="text/javascript">                                                                                                                  
/* <![CDATA[ */ 
    for (var count = 1; count <= 90; ++count ) {
        document.write(count);
        if (count % 3 ==0 && count % 5 == 0)
                document.write("&nbsp; FizzBuzz <br \>")
        else 
            if (count % 3 == 0)
                document.write("&nbsp; Fizz")
        else
            if (count % 5 == 0) 
                document.write("&nbsp; Buzz")
        document.write("<br />")      
    }
/* ]]> */
</script>
```

the question i have is my code written in one of the best ways possible for what I am doing?
what could i do differently for it to be written more efficiently?

Comment: you could store the result of `count % 3 ==0` and `count % 5 ==0` in a variable and reuse it in the condition

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on [codereview.se].

Comment: Sounds like someone is taking an interview test.

Comment: `count % 3 == 0` is just `!(count % 3)`

Comment: thanks for all the input, sorry that this is the wrong section, didn't know there was a specific code review section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using if logics you could use switch

```
for (var count = 1; count <= 90; ++count ) {
    document.write(count);
    var logics = (count % 3 ==0) + '-' + (count % 5 == 0);
    switch(logics){
      case 'true-false':{ document.write("&nbsp; Fizz"); break;}
      case 'false-true':{ document.write("&nbsp; Buzz"); break;}
      case 'true-true' :{ document.write("&nbsp; FizzBuzz <br>"); break;}
    }
    document.write("<br />")      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did several things here. First, I reduced the amount of code to make everything more readable. Second, I named the results of the tests to better indicate what they were (is divisible by 3 and is divisible by 5). I also updated the code to reflect the requirements exactly as you stated them. You said that you only needed a line break when FizzBuzz was printed. There was no indication that you needed any other line breaks.

The last thing I did was reduce the redundant tests. If a number is divisible by both 3 and 5, it will print Fizz first (isDivBy3) and will print Buzz right after (since it's isDivBy5), then will add the linebreak.

```
<script type="text/javascript">                                                                                                                  
    for (var count = 1; count <= 90; ++count ) {
        var isDivBy3 = !(count % 3);
        var isDivBy5 = !(count % 5);

        if( isDivBy3 ) document.write('Fizz');
        if( isDivBy5 ) document.write('Buzz');

        if( isDivBy3 && isDivBy5 ) document.write('<br/>');   
    }
</script>
```